# Change text value when button is pressed with directives in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here's my [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0okpxocz/1/)

I basically want to be able to change the text when a button is pressed. I have tried with both `$observe` and `$watch` inside `link`, but I still don't manage to get it working.

Code:

```
(function(){

    angular.module('app', [])


    .directive('testDirective', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                title: '@'
            },
            template: '<div>this is a {{ title }}</div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                //?
            }
        };
    });

})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass data as scope variable, you should not pass it as a string if you want to track changes.

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gopinathshiva/0okpxocz/2/), replace counter data with your desired data. Hope this helps

```
<div ng-controller='myctrl'>
    <test-directive title="counter"></test-directive>
    <hr></hr>
    <button type="button" ng-click = 'onclickbutton()'>Change names</button>
</div>
```

```
(function(){      

    angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('myctrl',function($scope){
        $scope.counter = 0;
        $scope.onclickbutton = function(){
           $scope.counter++;             
        }        
    })

    .directive('testDirective', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                title: '='
            },
            template: '<div>this is a {{ title }}</div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            }
        };
    });

})();
```